# Regex - comment out sql constraint

Tags: sql, regex, notepad++

With a regex I want comment out constraint by matching 'CONSTRAINT ... ( ))' and replacing it with '\*CONSTRAINT ... ( ))*\'. Operator . * in notepad++ matches the whole document so I cannot use it.

I was thinking of something like the following however some modifications are needed:

```
CONSTRAINT[\w\s]*\)\)
```

Input:

```
    modified_date datetime NULL,
    etl_id int NULL,
    etl_date smalldatetime NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_WORK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    work_id ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
)
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't forget the `,` before the `CONSTRAINT` keyword.

Comment: This is almost an impossible task to do with regex, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do :

search for : `(,\s*CONSTRAINT.+?\)\s+\))`
replace by : `/*$1*/`

I haven't the english version of Notepad++, but I think the labels are OK.

Verify that `regex` is selected and also `. includes \n`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your regex non-greedy:

```
 CONSTRAINT\([^)]+\)\)
```